# AR marker detection in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in  which the **AR Marker** is detected  using camera and compared with existing markers if the match found respective video is fetched and played in android. Is there is inbuilt SDK or API is there? Guide how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I use this SDK for Augmented Reality.
https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk
You can use native android or if you want to develop cross platform, you can use Unity SDK.
This page may will help you to your choice.
http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks

Comment: Thanks Cuneyt. while importing vuforia SDK with samples Null pointer exception is thrown. unable to test it? kindly share your thoughts how to implement it...

Comment: I used just Unity SDK. I tracked the exception on Log Screen and develop on my computer's camera and it worked on android phone, because unity is cross platform.

Comment: Unable to implement Unity SDK in Android Studio or Eclipse. In which platform you have implemented.could you guide please